# Get data of 2 different dates in 2 different columns sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, join

I have a sql table having columns  Name, VisitingDate, StayTime
I want a query which can give me data in which in 1 column I can get data of thismonthvisit and other column I can get data of lastmonthvisit and in 3rd column I can data of summation of StayTime of particular person .

Database Table : --

| Name | VisitingDate | StayTime(in minutes) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2021-04-20 | 5 |
| A | 2021-04-21 | 15 |
| A | 2021-03-20 | 10 |
| B | 2021-03-20 | 5 |

Result Wanted : --

| Name | Thismonthvisit | TotalStayTimeThismonth(in minutes) | LastmonthVisit | TotalStayTimelastmonth(in minutes) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 20 | 1 | 10 |
| B | 0 | 0 | 1 | 5 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for :

```
select name,
SUM(CASE WHEN FORMAT(VisitingDate, 'YYYYMM') = FORMAT(getdate(),'YYYYMM') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ThisMonthVisit,
SUM(CASE WHEN FORMAT(VisitingDate, 'YYYYMM') = FORMAT(getdate(),'YYYYMM') THEN StayTime ELSE 0 END) AS TotalStayTimeThisMonth,
SUM(CASE WHEN FORMAT(VisitingDate, 'YYYYMM') = FORMAT(dateadd(month, -1, getdate()),'YYYYMM') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS LastMonthVisit,
SUM(CASE WHEN FORMAT(VisitingDate, 'YYYYMM') = FORMAT(dateadd(month, -1, getdate()),'YYYYMM') THEN StayTime ELSE 0 END) AS TotalStayTimeLastMonth
from MyTable
where FORMAT(VisitingDate, 'YYYYMM') > FORMAT(dateadd(month, -2, getdate()),'YYYYMM')
group by Name
```

[**SEE DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=98066be39a78f8b0edfb9c83a36f6f15)

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation:

```
select name,
       sum(case when month(visitingdate) = month(getdate())
                then 1 else 0
           end) as cnt_thismonth,
       sum(case when month(visitingdate) = month(getdate())
                then staytime else 0
           end) staytime_thismonth,
       sum(case when month(visitingdate) <> month(getdate())
                then 1 else 0
           end) as cnt_lastmonth,
       sum(case when month(visitingdate) <> month(getdate())
                then staytime else 0
           end) staytime_lastmonth
from t
where visitingdate >= dateadd(month, -1, datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1))
group by name;
```